# Data Report Which Technology

Tags: gps

I want to create a small position reporter for cars. I found some good GPS Modules with which i could collect data. But i'm unsure with what technology i should send the data.

A possibility would be to setup a service in the www which is feeded by the arduinos.

I want to track the data live. so i think GPRS should be the right choice ?
Or more better are there any shields which make this GPRS LOG and SEND as a package ?

Which GPRS hardware would you use ?
Would you use something else?

Any hints are very welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually find all the information for what you want to do on the formal Arduino.cc website. [They suggest a GSM shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield):

[image]

But of course you can find many other GSM shields for purchase. Most of them works the same. Arduino.cc also offer a [nice GSM Library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM), with which you [can perform HTTP GET/POST](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesWebClient) queries to a remote webserver (visible over the web).

You can select whatever web server technology you prefer for receiving the data. Using NodeJS, PHP, MVC.NET or any other, you could expose a REST API to perform the update from the Arduino+GSM Shield side using HTTP.

The web server then could analyze the incoming data and display it in any way you like.

Comment: I would add that feeding datas in www through an internet access is going to put some undefined time delay in recording and forwarding datas online. And this is what he wants to achieve.

Comment: I think that the average GSM latency can be considered to be 'live', as much as any other online service/game you used on your smartphone

Comment: yes. With live i mean "where has it been in the last minute or so"